# Coinbase OAuth list notifications

Tags: coinbase-api

I am trying to set up a webhook to receive notifications about my OAuth connected users in my app. I have added the appropriate scope `wallet:notifications:read` when getting the token through OAuth and then I request the `GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/notifications` endpoint to test it out before setting up the webhook. I am using the python client library so my code looks like this.

```
client = OAuthClient(token.access_token, token.refresh_token)
notifications = client.get_notifications()
```

When I do that, I get an error saying
`coinbase.wallet.error.InvalidScopeError: APIError(id=invalid_authentication_method): This endpoint is only available for API key authentication`.

I am confused about why this is happening because the [docs](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/notifications) say that I can set up notifications with Coinbase Connect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Docs on the page your linked recommend this for testing:

> Testing notifications
>
> Since notifications must always be available in a publicly accessible URL, you might run into issues while starting to build your application in a local environment. The easiest way to get started testing notifications is to use a tool like RequestBin. Once you have created a temporary webhook, you can set it to your application settings. It’s important to use this only for development, as you should never leak notification data to public.